# Audio conversion with ffmpeg on cygwin fails

Tags: ffmpeg, cygwin, mp3

I have installed ffmpeg on cygwin from source code. I need to convert mp3 files to raw audio, but it fails with the following error message:

```
Assertion !link->frame_requested || link->flags & FF_LINK_FLAG_REQUEST_LOOP failed
at libavfilter/avfilter.c:360
```

Do I have some codec missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the full output of ffmpeg (audio metadata snipped):

```
$ ffmpeg -i 2quickstart.mp3 -ac 1 -ar 11025 -f s16le -t 20 -ss 10 2quickstart.raw
ffmpeg version 2.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 20 2013 13:26:12 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration:
  libavutil      52. 48.101 / 52. 48.101
  libavcodec     55. 39.101 / 55. 39.101
  libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
[mp3 @ 0x80022040] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '2quickstart.mp3':
  Metadata:
--snip--
  Duration: 00:03:37.87, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 255 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
Output #0, s16le, to '2quickstart.raw':
  Metadata:
--snip--
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 11025 Hz, mono, s16, 176 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 -> pcm_s16le)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Assertion !link->frame_requested || link->flags & FF_LINK_FLAG_REQUEST_LOOP failed
at libavfilter/avfilter.c:360
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: The command looks alright. Do you have a sample for us? We could also consider reporting a bug. Or have you tried downloading a recent static build from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com?

Comment: Does the command and same input work on a different system? Also, if it is a bug, it would be nice to know if it is a regression (if it worked on a previous ffmpeg version) or not. The builds from zeranoe could possibly be used to test for a regression.

Comment: The command works for me on Ubuntu. Also, the Zeranoe build works well on Cygwin, which solves the problem for me.

Comment: If anyone wants to test, the MP3 I used is here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzBl7YgNOj-VNjNjLVZXX3BMU28